# sequelize association scope using column value

Tags: sequelize.js

I've read sequelize doc about [Association Scopes](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/association-scopes.html). The example there is:

```
  const Bar = sequelize.define('bar', { status: DataTypes.STRING });
  Foo.hasMany(Bar, {
      scope: {
          status: 'open'
      },
      as: 'openBars'
  });
```

But I'd like to add one more condition to the scope based on a column value.
E.g.:

```
  const Bar = sequelize.define('bar', { status: DataTypes.STRING, userId: DataType.INTEGER });
  Foo.hasMany(Bar, {
      scope: {
          status: 'open',
          userId: Foo.userId // <-- something like this 
      },
      as: 'openBars'
  });
```

Is it possible? What would be the right syntax?

Comment: sequelize-typescript syntax would be even much better, but vanilla sequelize syntax is fine

Comment: Does the way you tried works? Did you get any error?